# Remap <leader>q to exit vim

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm relatively new to vim rebinds; I am trying to map `<leader>q` to exit vim, but the following rebind does not seem to work:

```
map <leader>q :q<cr>
```

However, all of the following seem to be working:

```
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>

map <leader>tn :tabnew<cr>
map <leader>to :tabonly<cr>
map <leader>tc :tabclose<cr>
map <leader>tm :tabmove
map <leader>t<leader> :tabnext
```

I'm using this basic [vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc/blob/master/vimrcs/basic.vim) configuration as a template

**Edit:** turns out it was a completely unrelated problem, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, I was defining `map <leader>q :q<cr>` before the line `let mapleader = ";"`, which meant that for `<leader>q`, the leader key was either undefined or mapped to some other key.

To future beginner vim users out there, always define `mapleader` *before* you add any `map <leader>X` rebinds!

Comment: Also to future beginner vim users out there. There are a [myriad ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-vim) to exit vim. The most convenient by far is `ZZ`, which is even easier than `<leader>q`.

Comment: `ZZ` actually writes the current file if modified (see `:help zz`). `ZQ` is equivalent to `:q!`, but there's no built-in equivalent to :q`.